# Python: Apply .apply() with a self-defined function to a Data Frame- why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to apply a self-defined function by using apply() to a data frame. Goal is to calculate the mean of each row  / column with a self-defined function. But it doesn't work, probably I still don't understand the logic of .apply() fully. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"A":[50,60,70],"B":[80,90,100]})

def m(x):
    x.sum()/len(x)
    return x

d.apply(m(),axis=0)
```

Comment: The problem is simply that you do not `return` the result in your function, but rather the input `x` itself. `x.sum() / len(x)` does *not* modify `x`, but returns a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible the best way is a vectorized solution:

```
df = d.sum() / len(d)
```

Your solution is possible too, but you need to change to return the values, and also in `apply` remove `()`, finally `axis=0` is the default value for that parameter, so it can also be removed:

```
def m(x):
    return x.sum()/len(x)

df = d.apply(m)
```

Comment: If you were to not use a vectorized solution, I would suggest using `.agg()` when you want to apply functions that transform a column to a single value @GeorgieBaul.